# const char* returns true in C++ CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

since yesterday I have been struggling to turn text into label with code from another class, I came to this:

```
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
TestApp::UI_Error form("test", "test");
Application::Run(% form);
```

Using the above code, i display a winapi form that receives "test", "test" as 2x const char* on loading, the problem appears when im trying to set the text in labels using these variables
The code looks like this:

```
public:
    UI_Error(const char* errorText, const char* errorCode)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this->testLabel->Text = System::Convert::ToString(errorText);
    }
```

For some reason, each time the return value shown in the win forms window is "true", although it should be "test" here, does anyone know the solution?

I tried to use std::string instead of const char*, unfortunately for some reason i get the error code that a static variable is required :(

Comment: No overload for const char*, that an implicit conversion from a pointer to bool is acceptable is an unfortunate C++ wart.  Change the constructor argument types to String^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong here, but `System::Convert::ToString()` seems not to have a method that accepts a `const char*` pointer. It looks like it gets cast to something else.

Try this instead:

```cpp
Text = gcnew System::String(errorText);
```